# How to apply a user defined function between rows in pandas using both rows values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have two rows of data in a Pandas data frame and want to operate each column separately with a function that includes both values e.g.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2], "z": [2, 6], "i": [3, 12], "j": [4, 20], "y": [5, 30]})
    x   z   i   j   y
0   1   2   3   4   5
1   2   6   12  20  30
```

The function is something like the row 2 val minus row 1 val, divided by the latter - for each column separately e.g.

(row2-row1)/row2

so I can get the following

```
0.5  0.667   0.75   0.8   0.833
```

Based on the following links

[how to apply a user defined function column wise on grouped data in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62261187/how-to-apply-a-user-defined-function-column-wise-on-grouped-data-in-pandas)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apply-a-function-to-each-row-or-column-in-dataframe-using-pandas-apply/

https://pythoninoffice.com/pandas-how-to-calculate-difference-between-rows

[Groupby and apply a defined function - Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59646230/groupby-and-apply-a-defined-function-pandas)

I tried the following

```
df.apply(lambda x,y: (x + y)/y, axis=0)
```

This does not work as it expects y as an argument

```
df.diff()
```

This works but then it is not exactly the function I want.

Does anyone know how to achieve the result I expect?

Comment: can you make 1 more row in example and edit desired output?  2row is short to understand perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing many things I found out that it was not required to include two variables in the Lambda function (x,y), but just one and treat that as a vector with all values in the column, so the following solved the issue

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x[1] - x[0]) / x[1], axis=0)
```

This avoids having a result with NaN in the first row.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.diff(1).div(df)
```

output

```
    x   z    i    j   y
0   NaN NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
1   0.5 0.67 0.75 0.8 0.83
```

With a short example, I answered. If I'm misunderstanding something, edit your example more long. I'll answer again.